# a member function check() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26.
In a .ctp file, I have a few like of codes like this:

```
$sess = $this->Session->check('user');
if($sess){
// do soemthing
}
else{
// do soemthing then
}
```

But I got this error then:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   check() on a non-object in
>   /home/vol12/mysite.com/htdocs/app/views/layouts/testing1.ctp
>   on line 10

Can I use the Check method in a .ctp file to check if a session exists?

Comment: Does `check()` exist for Session in 1.26? I know 1.3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a session component for use in controllers, of course, that is referenced as `$this->Session`. What you're looking for, I think is the session *helper* that is available to views. This is referenced simply as `$session`, IIRC. I wanted to verify that (it's been a while since I had to use it), but can't find it in the docs at the moment. What I think you want is:

```
$sess = $session->check('user');
```

Comment: agreed.Helper calling doesn't need `$this`.

Answer (score 1):

I can do this in 1.2.5:

```
if ($session->read('Auth.User')){ ... }
```

see the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/view/484/Session which is brief but explicit. *Note that you cannot write to the session from the view*.